# Git Revert To Previous Commits Unmerged Files Disregard Unmerged Files as well

Tags: git

Here is my git log

```
$ git log
commit b5865d75efbd7bdf5b28aef6526f96ebd971e95c
Author: user <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 21:20:17 2014 -0400

    new work

commit 7ee27d135a733fe709279f7752f5844da3102f9e
Author: user <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 20:44:33 2014 -0400

    added password_for_form_show to attr_accessor

commit f3decd1232c6884c14cd082c3129e77ddd2b3bab
Author: user <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 14:21:36 2014 -0400

    phase 3.5

commit 99804b8f0adc572021f773dea5e660186d11a88b
Author: user <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 12:19:13 2014 -0400

    jquery stuff done
```

I just checked out the newest commit from my branch

```
git checkout b5865d75efbd7bdf5b28aef6526f96ebd971e95c
```

The commits above are published on github.

I tried to do this next

```
git revert HEAD~3
```

I want to permanently revert back to this stage both locally and up on github

```
commit 99804b8f0adc572021f773dea5e660186d11a88b
Author: user <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 12:19:13 2014 -0400

    jquery stuff done
```

when I do the command above I am getting this

```
error: 'revert' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
```

when I do

```
git status
```

I am getting this

```
$ git status
# HEAD detached at b5865d7
# You are currently reverting commit 99804b8.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
#   (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      app/views/users/trial_signup.html.erb
```

please note that I do not want my local commits/files as well. How do I force the reverts? I don't want to stash them because I don't want them. I don't want to commit and add and push.

Comment: I think you want `git reset` which would actually reset the HEAD to point to a previous commit and will discard any commits you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you perform a revert, git masters a *new* commit which negates the change made in the subject commit, and tries to apply the new change on top of your current HEAD. Certainly there could be merge conflicts at this stage. You have to resolve them as usually and then commit the new change. May be you need a rebase?